# Count line in a file and write the count into a new file using same name of the text in the folder

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write code to count the lines in each file inside my folder(`NewCode`), and I have that part working, but I also need to write the line count into a new file (in a new folder (`NewCodeOutput`)) with the same name as the text file that was read.

Here's my code:

```
string[] ori_Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\C#\NewCode\", "*.txt*", 
    SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

string path2 = @"D:\C#\NewCodeOutput\";

foreach (var file in ori_Files)
{
    using (StreamReader file1 = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        string line;
        int count = 0;

        while ((line = file1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(line);
            count++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: [Please take some time to read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), and then explain why you are unable to do what you have described - what is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  You'll need to modify the filename `file` to make it relative to the path2.  You can use the [path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods for this.  Then you will need to write the count to the new text file.  At the very least you could use [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Path.GetFileName to extract the file name, and then write the count.

```
var completeOutputPath = Path.Combine(path2,Path.GetFileName(file));
File.WriteAllText(completeOutputPath, $"Count:{count}");
```

This should appear before your Console.WriteLine(count) within the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Path.Combine` along with `Path.GetFileName` to generate the new path with the existing file's name.

You can also use the `System.IO.File` class to simplify the line counting and file writing:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\C#\NewCode\", "*.txt*",
    SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(@"D:\C#\NewCodeOutput\", Path.GetFileName(file)),
        File.ReadAllLines(file).Length.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and it's work! But how can i grab some data from (file)?

Comment: `string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);` reads all the lines of the file into an array. `string allFileText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);` reads the entire contents of the file into a single string. Either of those should do the trick. :)

Comment: so put either one inside the foreach and substring it? because i need some part of the line only.

Comment: Yep. Give it a try and come back if you get stuck!